# TikZ: decoration - random steps: how to get twice exactly the same shape?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, random-numbers

I'm creating a beamer presentation, in which I use TikZ.

I am making a figure, on which I would like to highlight something (using `\only<>` command). My figure contains an ellipse that is decorated with random steps:

```
...
\node[ellipse,minimum width=1cm,black!30,decorate,decoration={random steps,segment length=0.2cm,amplitude=.1cm}] {}; 
\only<1>{
\node (n) at (0,0) {A};
}
\only<2>{
\node (n) at (0,0) {B};
}
```

The ellipse is rendered in differenlty. How can I make it to render the same? or what other decoration can I use to get a similar effect to random steps?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You can highlight code using the braces (`{}`) button over the edit window, or with backticks (`) for [inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). It is always preferable to post complete [minimal working examples](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) rather than code snippets because this helps people to answer you.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The problem was due to the seed: if you add `\pgfmathsetseed{<integer number>}` before the first `\node` the seed used to generate random numbers is reset in each slide, forcing the path to be the same.

Here's a complete example (I took some liberty with the size of the shape):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,decorations,decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetseed{23654}
\node[thick,draw,ellipse,minimum width=3cm,minimum height=1.5cm,black!30,decorate,decoration={random steps,segment length=0.3cm,amplitude=.3cm}] {}; 
\only<1>{
\node (n) at (0,0) {A};
}
\only<2>{
\node (n) at (0,0) {B};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Glad of having helped you. I would courteously suggest for the future to upvote all answers you find useful, including those to others' questions and to check/accept the best answers to your own questions by clicking the green tick on the left-hand side of the answer.

Comment: I'd love to upvote, but I don't have enough reputation yet :)

Comment: No problems: my comment should be intended as good recommendation for new users. `:)`

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino How to get a closed curve?

Comment: @Sigur: for that you have to operate on the decoration, try to fix the amplitude, segment length, (the path if you don't use a node construction).