# Beamer's (implicit) options regarding tikzpictures and shadows

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tikz-styles, viewers, option-clash

While trying to use the [torn page effect](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86151/34551) in a `beamer` document, I was confronted to an unexpected problem.

If you just take the the code of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86151/34551) and compile it, you get:

[image: Screenshot of the torn effect on article]

If you just change the class to `beamer` (and comment the `geometry` package), you get:

[image: Screenshot of the torn effect on beamer]

A thin (ugly) line just appeared at the end of the shadow (which is not quite the same either). I tried *a lot* of options and modification of the code, looked at the `beamer` documentation (ouch), but could not find any clue on how to remove this thin line (or at least, makes it white).

Comment: In both cases, I commented the `shade=bilinear interpolation`, which caused an error at compilation.

Comment: The option in version 3.0 should be `shading=bilinear interpolation`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I added a comment on [the original question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86150/torn-page-effect/86151#86151) and a [closely related one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86372/torn-paper-matching-up-the-torn-edges). However, it does not solve that problem.

Comment: Yes, I know it doesn't solve the problem. I just wanted to give the proper option.

Comment: The output looks fine on my machine after correcting the TikZ option mentioned by @GonzaloMedina. See: http://i.stack.imgur.com/mEnJ0.png

Comment: This is a viewer issue. I can confirm the problem using Okular and the TeXworks viewer, but the problem disappears using Acrobat Reader.

Comment: Most viewers can't handle PS based shadings. So test everything on Acrobat.

Comment: I'm on debian and you are right. The error shows on Okular, but Adobe Reader and Foxit Reader just display the output correctly. But _how come_ this is sensitive to the class ?!?! Anyway, I'll accept anyone answering "it is a viewer issue", thanks a lot.

Comment: @percusse It does depend on your aims, though. If you want to make sure something looks OK no matter which viewer a reader uses, it is a reason to test with Okular or another poppler-based viewer. (One person's modus ponens is another's modus tollens...) Why would it be class-dependent, though?

Comment: 1) I was looking for an explanation of this difference. It appears to be sensitive to the viewer, so I regard this question as off-topic. 2) However, it *is* class-dependant. Those two `.tex`, compiled with the same engine and viewed with *the same* viewer (okular in that case) have different behaviors: in one case the shadow is correct, not in the other. And the only difference is the class.

Comment: @cfr If it doesn't work in Acrobat then you can think of a TeX problem otherwise almost always it is a viewer issue. Especially with fadings XeTeX is another smoking gun. Makes life easier for debugging.

Comment: @percusse Yes, of course.

Comment: @Clément That I don't understand. If the problem is that the viewer cannot handle the shading, why should the class make any difference?

Comment: That is the effect though. Okular has no problem if it is `article` - only with `beamer`. It is interesting, because I've had problems with shadings go the other way i.e. artefacts in Adobe which didn't appear in Okular. (Probably an old version of the software since it was a university copy of Adobe.) So now I make my shadings overshoot the page dimensions in `beamer` so I don't get unexpected blocks of colour when I show the slides in class. (I test in Okular but display in Adobe as they've only got Windows.)

Comment: @cfr : I cannot explain that neither. But you were aware of the difference that makes the classes in the shadow treatment of viewers, too. Did you try to get any explanation?

Comment: @Clément Well, in that case I assumed a straightforward viewer problem i.e. that Adobe did something odd in rendering the slides, whereas Okular did not (or did something less odd, at least). It didn't occur to me to test with anything other than `beamer` - I only tried that with your example a few hours ago. So there was no explanation really to seek.

Comment: Related question: [Ugly artifacts with pgf-blur and beamer (and poppler)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287157/ugly-artifacts-with-pgf-blur-and-beamer-and-poppler)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question gets some votes but the answer is somehow hidden in the comments.
To sum up: this difference is due to the pdf viewer.

Everything works fine with Adobe Reader, which should always be the reference.

The reason why most viewers can display the effect when the class `article` is used, and not when the class `beamer` is used remains a mystery.

For the record, the code tested was

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}   % To generate test text 
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,calc,shadows.blur,shadings}
\pgfmathsetseed{1} % To have predictable results
% Define a background layer, in which the parchment shape is drawn
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}

% This is the base for the fractal decoration. It takes a random point between the start and end, and
% raises it a random amount, thus transforming a segment into two, connected at that raised point
% This decoration can be applied again to each one of the resulting segments and so on, in a similar
% way of a Koch snowflake.
\pgfdeclaredecoration{irregular fractal line}{init}
{
  \state{init}[width=\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance]
  {
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{random*\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance}{(random*\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude-0.02)*\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance}{0pt}}
  }
}

% define some styles
\tikzset{
   paper/.style={draw=black!10, blur shadow, shading=bilinear interpolation,
                 lower left=black!20, upper left=black!15, upper right=white, lower right=black!10},
   irregular border/.style={decoration={irregular fractal line, amplitude=0.2},
           decorate,
     },
   ragged border/.style={ decoration={random steps, segment length=7mm, amplitude=2mm},
           decorate,
   }
}

% Macro to draw the shape behind the text, when it fits completly in the
% page
\def\tornpaper#1{
\tikz{
  \node[inner sep=1em] (A) {#1};  % Draw the text of the node
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}  % Draw the shape behind
  \fill[paper] % recursively decorate the bottom border
        decorate[irregular border]{decorate{decorate{decorate{decorate[ragged border]{
        ($(A.south east) - (0, random*5mm)$) -- ($(A.south west) - (0, random*5mm)$)
        }}}}}
        -- (A.north west) -- (A.north east) -- cycle;
  \end{pgfonlayer}}
}


\begin{document}
\noindent
\tornpaper{
\parbox{.9\textwidth}{\lipsum[11]}
}

\bigskip
\noindent
\tornpaper{
\parbox{.9\textwidth}{\lipsum[15]}
}
\end{document}
```