# Ugly artifacts with pgf-blur and beamer (and poppler)

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, shadows

I am trying to add blur shadows to a beamer presentation using the [pgf-blur](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf-blur) package.  Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[minimum height=1cm, minimum width=3cm,
  rounded corners, fill=red!30, blur shadow] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, when I try to present my slides using any of the poppler-based renderers (like xpdf, evince, okular, impressive), I get an extremely ugly artifact at the border and especially corners.  Here is what it looks like:

[image: artifacts]

Interestingly, the problem goes away if I do the same thing in a `\documentclass{article}`.  Here is a screenshot of the same image without beamer:

[image: rendered with \documentclass{article}]

Because the problem does not happen with mupdf, this may actually just be a bug in libpoppler.  However, libpoppler is so prevalent that I need to find a way to work around it.  The fact that the bug goes away without beamer gives me some hope there is a way around this, but I have no idea what beamer might be doing to cause the artifact.  I'd also be happy with an alternative to pgf-blur, if there is one.

Comment: You don't need blur here. Beamer has its own shadows and they are hardly distinguishable.

Comment: @percusse Any advice on how to use those shadows in a tikz picture?

Comment: Yes  it is given in the `shadows` library which beamer uses

Comment: @percusse You mean like in beamerbaseboxes.sty, the stuff that happens `\ifbmb@shadow`?  It doesn't seem to be using much of a library but rather implementing a lot of the stuff inline with low-level pgf commands...

Comment: See the `shadows` library of TikZ. TikZ also uses a lot of PGF whioch doesn't mean it is bad.

Comment: @percusse Yeah, it works if I use a regular shadow from stock TikZ instead of blur shadow from pgf-blur, but the blur shadows look so much better.  What's frustrating is that they work fine in article mode, so I just wonder what beamer is doing...

Comment: Is there anything to do with http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226598/beamers-implicit-options-regarding-tikzpictures-and-shadows ?

Comment: @Symbol1 Indeed, this could well be the same issue.  Too bad the other question doesn't have a solution, either, or that would be the first thing to try...

Comment: Here's a question where a similar artifact in an older version of acroread seems to be related to a show thin lines "optimization" http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11272/faded-drop-shadow-using-tikz-based-rounded-rectangle

Answer (score 5):

Here is a workaround:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\tikzset{
  my blur shadow layer/.style={
    preaction={fill=black,fill opacity=.025,transform canvas={xshift=#1,yshift=-1*#1}},
  },
  my blur shadow/.style={
    my blur shadow layer/.list={.3pt,.6pt,...,2.7pt},
  },
}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[minimum height=1cm, minimum width=3cm,
  rounded corners, fill=red!30,
  blur shadow,
  ] {};
\node[minimum height=1cm, minimum width=3cm,
  rounded corners, fill=orange!30,
  my blur shadow,
  ] at (0, -1.2){};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, which definitely gets rid of the artifacts.  Unfortunately, now the shadow looks too small--it's exactly the size of the shape, when it should be slightly bigger.  Any suggestions on how to make it look more like a shadow?  Maybe shift it left and down separately or something?