# Different styles for horizontal intermediate lines in mdframed while paginating

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, mdframed

I have a multipage frame built with `mdframed` with method `tikz`. I need to frame with lines all its parts on every page.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage[paperwidth=155mm, paperheight=35mm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    \begin{mdframed}[
        frametitle="Example of the frame",
        linecolor=red,
        nobreak=false,
        everyline=true
    ]
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Utpurus elit,
        vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, fe-lis.
        Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget,
        consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
    \end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

I'm searching for a solution (easy or complex) to change styles for all those intermediate horizontal lines that appear automatically with frame breaks. In my case, I need them as a "snaked" zigzag (the one from the `tikz` library is fine for me).

If you know solutions with any other packages (e.g. `tcolorbox`), it's also acceptable ...

**This is what I have**

[image]

**This is what I want**

[image]

Comment: Look at: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86150/torn-page-effect?noredirect=1&lq=1 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86372/torn-paper-matching-up-the-torn-edges

Comment: No, this is not what I want

Answer (score 2):

Well, after some research I've found a way how to do that with `tcolorbox`. The `mdframed` solution still is not clear for me (any ideas?).

If someone needs it, here that I have done:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{snakes}
\usepackage[paperwidth=155mm, paperheight=20mm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
        enhanced,
        breakable,
        sharp corners=all,
        colback=white,
        frame hidden,
        parbox=false,
        boxsep=0pt,
        left=10pt,
        right=10pt,
        bottom=10pt,
        top=2.5pt,
        toptitle=10pt,
        bottomtitle=2.5pt,
        before skip=0.75\baselineskip plus 2pt,
        after skip=0.75\baselineskip plus 2pt,
        overlay first={%
            \draw[line width=0.5pt, red] (frame.north west)--(frame.north east);
            \draw[line width=0.2pt, red, decorate, decoration={zigzag, segment length=3pt, amplitude=1pt}] (frame.south west)--(frame.south east);

            \draw[line width=0.5pt, red] ($(frame.north west) + (0, 0.25pt)$)--(frame.south west);
            \draw[line width=0.5pt, red] ($(frame.north east) + (0, 0.25pt)$)--(frame.south east);
        },
        overlay middle={%
            \draw[line width=0.1pt, red, decorate, decoration={zigzag, segment length=3pt, amplitude=1.0pt}] (frame.south west)--(frame.south east);
            \draw[line width=0.1pt, red, decorate, decoration={zigzag, segment length=3pt, amplitude=1.0pt}] (frame.north west)--(frame.north east);

            \draw[line width=0.5pt, red] (frame.north west)--(frame.south west);
            \draw[line width=0.5pt, red] (frame.north east)--(frame.south east);
        },
        overlay last={%
            \draw[line width=0.1pt, red, decorate, decoration={zigzag, segment length=3pt, amplitude=1.0pt}] (frame.north west)--(frame.north east);
            \draw[line width=0.5pt, red] (frame.south west)--(frame.south east);

            \draw[line width=0.5pt, red] (frame.north west)--($(frame.south west) - (0, 0.25pt)$);
            \draw[line width=0.5pt, red] (frame.north east)--($(frame.south east) - (0, 0.25pt)$);
        },
        overlay unbroken={%
            \draw[line width=0.5pt, red] (frame.north west)--(frame.north east);
            \draw[line width=0.5pt, red] (frame.south west)--(frame.south east);

            \draw[line width=0.5pt, red] (frame.north west)--($(frame.south west) - (0, 0.25pt)$);
            \draw[line width=0.5pt, red] (frame.north east)--($(frame.south east) - (0, 0.25pt)$);
        }
    ]
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Utpurus elit,
        vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, fe-lis.
        Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget,
        consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image: This how it looks like]