# TikZ: Handdrawn boxes/arrows/circles for flowcharts

Tags: tikz-pgf, fun

I saw the following style of boxes in Aditya's [presentation](http://www.ece.mcgill.ca/~amahaj1/talks/gerad-2012.pdf) as he mentioned it during his TeXTalk. I am almost positive that Aditya is using `Metafun` for this.

But I was wondering how would one go about doing this in `tikz`. The cool thing about the boxes and arrows is that they keep changing with every new instance. Some sort of randomisation is going on.

[image: Aditya's boxes]

Comment: look at this example:http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/hand-drawn-lines/

Answer (score 15):

Along the site there are several references for hand drawn lines with TikZ (most of them from our hand drawn-guru percusse):

- [Create xkcd style diagram in TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74878/create-xkcd-style-diagram-in-tex)
- [Simulating hand-drawn lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39296/simulating-hand-drawn-lines)
- [TikZ two-blocks matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69990/tikz-two-blocks-matrix)

Actually, to let the shape change in every instance is something almost straightforward since is the normal behaviour unless you specify a seed: see [TikZ: decoration - random steps: how to get twice exactly the same shape?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70578/tikz-decoration-random-steps-how-to-get-twice-exactly-the-same-shape)

An example exploiting the `oo` module:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgfmodule{oo}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,decorations.pathmorphing}

\tikzset{pencil draw/.style={
    draw,
    decorate,
    decoration={random steps,segment length=3mm,amplitude=0.2mm}
  }
}


\pgfooclass{module}{

 % class attributes
 \attribute text;
 \attribute text width=2.5cm;
 \attribute label;
 \attribute width=3cm;
 \attribute height=1cm;

 % constructor method
 \method module() {
 }

 \method text(#1) {
  \pgfooset{text}{#1}
 }

 \method set text width(#1) {
  \pgfooset{text width}{#1}
 }

 \method set label(#1) {
  \pgfooset{label}{#1}
 }

 \method set width(#1) {
  \pgfooset{width}{#1}
 }

 \method set height(#1) {
  \pgfooset{height}{#1}
 }

 \method draw(#1,#2) {
  \node [rectangle,
    thick,
    pencil draw,
    align=center,
    text width=\pgfoovalueof{text width},
    minimum width=\pgfoovalueof{width},
    minimum height=\pgfoovalueof{height},
    ] (\pgfoovalueof{label}) at (#1,#2) {\pgfoovalueof{text}};
 }

 \method place(#1) {
  \node [rectangle,
    thick,
    pencil draw,
    align=center,
    text width=\pgfoovalueof{text width},
    minimum width=\pgfoovalueof{width},
    minimum height=\pgfoovalueof{height},
    #1
    ] (\pgfoovalueof{label}) {\pgfoovalueof{text}};
 }

 \method connect(#1,#2) {
    \draw[-stealth,pencil draw,thick,decorate,decoration={raise=1mm}] (#1)--(#2);
    \draw[-stealth,pencil draw,thick,decorate,decoration={raise=1mm}] (#2)--(#1);   
 }

 % shortcut method to easily set labels, text and draw
 % use the \pgfoothis to refer to the current object
 \method set and draw(#1,#2,#3,#4) {
  \pgfoothis.set label(#1)
  \pgfoothis.text(#2)
  \pgfoothis.draw(#3,#4)
 }

 % shortcut method to easily set labels, text and place
 % objects
 \method set and place(#1,#2,#3) {
  \pgfoothis.set label(#1)
  \pgfoothis.text(#2)
  \pgfoothis.place(#3)
 }

 % shortcut method to easily set the dimensions
 \method set dimensions(#1,#2,#3) {
  \pgfoothis.set width(#1)
  \pgfoothis.set height(#2)
  \pgfoothis.set text width(#3)
 }

}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Diagram}
\centering
\only<1-4>{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75, transform shape]
\pgfoonew \mod=new module()

\mod.set and draw(reg 1,Region 1,0,0)
\mod.set and place(reg 2,Region 2,right= 3cm of reg 1)
\mod.set and place(contr 1,Controller 1,below= 2cm of reg 1)
\mod.set and place(contr 2,Controller 2,right= 3cm of contr 1)

\mod.connect(reg 1,reg 2)
\mod.connect(reg 1,contr 1)
\mod.connect(reg 2,contr 2)
\mod.connect(contr 1,contr 2)

\node at ($(reg 1)!0.5!(reg 2)-(0,3ex)$) {Interconnect};
\node at ($(contr 1)!0.5!(contr 2)-(0,3ex)$) {Communication};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]